# Convert Raster object into Shapefile

Tags: r, shapefile, r-raster

Basically, I have a spLines Object with a bunch of lines, and after I am rasterizing it - `rast2 <- rasterize(spLines, rast,  fun='count')` - in order to get a grid frequency map. However, I'd like to convert and save that **rast2** Object into a **Shapefile**. Is that possible?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: do you have python installed on your machine?

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention, I am working with R, but I do have python in my machine. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

this [raster package](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/raster/) will do the trick but there's a much faster way to do it if you have python installed by using [gdal_polygonise.py](https://web.archive.org/web/20180716125119/http://gdal.org:80/gdal_utilities.html)

Comment: there's sample code for python here http://johnbaumgartner.wordpress.com/2012/07/26/getting-rasters-into-shape-from-r/

Comment: Thanks for your help, however, the only function that I found is **shapefile**, and according to the documentation, _only the three vector types (points, lines, and polygons) can be stored in shapeﬁles_, and my goal is to save the raster object into a **shapefile**.

Comment: see this questsion http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/70948/r-plotting-shapefile-with-geographical-raster-data

Comment: Yes, I found that function in the raster package's documentation.

Comment: it must be possible. yer man did it in python using the gdal utilities